# Can we share a websocket session to multiple users?

Tags: java, websocket

I am building an app for live streaming purpose. 
I am very new to web sockets, kindly correct me if I am asking anything wrong.

There is one main server and multiple device Clients.so there is one to many mapping between main server and device client.I am using web sockets to connect the main server and device client. main server is websocket server end and device is client end.So main server and device server connected thru web sockets that's fine , i can exchange msgs information from main server to device client and vice versa. Now i have a use case where multiple users are using single device, so in this case web socket session is only one and shared by multiple users of device. Now when multiple concurrent request are coming from device , how Main server will handle those request? i guess it will be race condition? How onMessage event at server side will handle concurrent request for same websocket session ?
There is only one Main Server but device server are many. there can be multiple user for a device server. 
I searched for this but dint get any answer to my problem. I will really appreciate any suggestions !

Comment: please format your question so that it's legible

Comment: Thank You Soumyaansh for your response.  I have tried to format my question. kindly suggest me and and help me on this if possible. Thanks in Advance